# When using MySQL, why is Entity Framework 4 trying to convert a long to a decimal?

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql, entity-framework

Whenever I have a table with a `BIGINT` primary key, I can insert new records, but can't update existing records. When I try to do an update, I get the following error:

`"The specified value is not an instance of type 'Edm.Decimal'"`

Sample model:

```
public class Model
{
    public long ModelID { get; set; }

    public DateTime ProcessedOn { get; set; }
}
```

Sample update code:

```
public bool SetModelProcessed(long id)
{
    var entity = db.models.SingleOrDefault(m => m.ModelID == id);

    entity.ProcessedOn = DateTime.Now;

    db.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(entity, System.Data.EntityState.Modified);

    db.SaveChanges();
 }
```

Even a model as simple as this one is failing for me. Anyone know what is happening?

**Edit**

I tried the code-first approach. Entity Framework 4.3 couldn't even generate the mySQL database which is apparently an issue for mySQL and versions of Entity Framework after the migration features were added.

Since downgrading to version 4.1.10715.0, `long` works, `ulong` still doesn't. EF won't acknowledge a property as the primary key if it's a `ulong`.

`EntityType 'Model' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.`

Using `long` instead of `ulong` isn't what I need, but it'll have to do I guess.

Comment: Can you show the db class that inherits from `DbContext`?

Comment: This isn't code-first, so the entities class inherits from ObjectContext. Do you want to see that class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many years later...
Use HasColumnType("long") in the OnModelCreating() method of your DbContext.
See [Entity Framework Core will not map to BigInteger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41843538/entity-framework-core-will-not-map-to-biginteger/71532299#71532299)

Answer (score 1):

If this happens to be an unsigned bigint in the database, then I believe it gets mapped to a decimal instead of a `long` - not sure why it doesn't just use a `ulong`. But I'd start there, make sure your bigint is signed.

Comment: Initially, I was using ulong. I found some articles that said EF didn't support mapping to unsigned types. so I tried with just a bigint/long, but have the same problem.

Comment: But you're sure it's a bigint in the database, not an unsigned bigint?

Comment: It was unsigned initially, when I was trying to use a ulong. I created a new table from scratch with just a bigint (unsigned) and date field to match the above model.